# Winter Bash opt-in fails on private beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta, winter-bash-2013

Clicking the "I Love Hats"-button on [a site in private beta](http://aviation.stackexchange.com) shows the "An error occurred while joining - please try again" message. Dev tools show this response from the server:

```
 {"ErrorMessage":"failed to opt in to winter bash"}
```

Comment: How come aviation got into beta before Ebooks???????

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn Ebooks is launching tomorrow. Aviation went first in part because [today is a special day in aviation history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason was an inconsistency between the settings: Aviation isn't activated as a hat-receiving site on [winterbash2013.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com), but our network default setting on the Q&A sites for "should the Winter Bash JavaScript" be included is "yes" (because that's 95 out of 111 sites). The newly created Aviation site inherited the network default and thus included the JavaScript. I've turned it off now; the site should focus on being born, not wearing hats :)

Comment: But... we want our hats! Especially the propeller-type ones!

Comment: So, the Chuck Yeager hat can be earned on every site *but* Aviation?  Oh the irony...

Comment: @Jamal Ebooks won't get it either ;)

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller: Wait, we have an <insert site here> site?

Comment: @Jamal Yep, [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com) is that very site.