# How do I earn the Old Hat hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, beta-sites

The description for the Old Hat says:

> have a user account created in the first month of the site's existence

How is "existence" defined? Private beta, public beta, non-beta, or something else?

I just created an account on the ~3 hour old [Aviation SE private beta](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), but I don't have the hat yet.

[image: Old Hat]

Comment: Patience young padawan...remember the Mogwai...

Comment: Some hats are rewarded once per day. Almost midnight!

Comment: @RoryAlsop In the past, it never took more than about a minute for me to get a hat after completing the requirements.

Comment: As Martijn says: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212230/154443

Comment: Aviation.SE is exclude from Winterbash this year.

Comment: @AnnaLear Why? Didn't they opt-in? And how could they have done that?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn They didn't opt in on account of not existing at all until yesterday. We want brand new sites to focus on building the site rather than chasing hats.

Comment: The focus thing makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise definition (because it's the most reasonable one that works on all sites, even the pre-SE2.0 sites) is *the user's creation date (hover over the "member for" value on the use profile for the precise time) is before the time when the site's Community user (user id -1) turned 31 days*.

Comment: What about merged accounts? Are they always taking the older/first account creation date?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, of course.

Comment: One last question related to merging: do hats get migrated e.g. user A with X hats being merged with user B having Y hats. Does the new account keep all hats, including the secret ones?

Answer (score 5):

Existence includes private beta.

I got it for br.SO just now, which is still in private beta.

Note, though, that other private beta sites launched during Winterbash will be excluded from the event and you can't earn any hats on them.

Comment: @Anna Hmm. IIRC hats still exist internally for sites which haven't opted in and a user which has opted in to hats can earn them on all sites. Are you sure about that?

Comment: [Reasonably sure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212207/155160), yes. You can't earn hats on private betas we're launching during Winterbash.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah, I see