# How to calculate age of Stack Overflow site?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know how can I calculate lifetime of **Stack Overflow** site from established time until just now? How old is it ?

> *'' sometimes , questions were from so long times ago , I want to compare them from start-time of **SO** ''*

Comment: Stack Overflow first opened public Beta in August 2008.

Comment: Somewhere between 6-8 weeks... Oh.. no wait...I think I'm confusing my memes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to https://stackexchange.com/ -> [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) -> [Change the view to list view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) -> You can find the site age in the last column. Here, you can see the age of any site.

To search old questions go to the questions list -> Search for any tag (if required) -> Click on *Newest* tab -> Click on [the last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?page=3697&sort=newest&pagesize=50) from paging.

Comment: yes really complete answer.. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to know exact age of any site without relying on the sites list or questions list is going to the Community user account of that site (`http://[site]/users/-1/community`) then the "member for" field is actually the age of the site. For example in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> [image]

Comment: Is that not made up though?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy no, I saw Nick (or maybe other dev) mention it at some point and made a mental note. Can't find it now but just try and see for yourself. If you find a site where this isn't true I'll be happy to stand corrected. :)

Comment: Just the 00:00:00 time sounds suspicious -- on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community the last seen time is before it was registered, if it's real...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it's 00:00:00 because the whole data was imported from external source (Jeff blog, I think) and as for "last seen" it's fake, a dev just entered it manually at some point. (nobody can really login as that user)

Comment: @Qantas: balpha mentioned it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212246/how-do-i-earn-the-old-hat-hat/212312#212312) (cc @Shadow!)

Comment: Thanks @Matt was looking for this answer but didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

@hims056 has a really good, efficient, easy answer.

However, if you like to do things the hard way and possibly not get correct results??? You can do it this way :

[image]

Comment: My second paragraph says the same but +1 for the image.

Comment: -1 for no free hand shapes. (j/k ;))

Comment: I got a little confuse with your **star** . what is it pointing ?

Comment: FWIW: The oldest question is actually oldest *undeleted* question. Actual first question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go (10K) which was quite ridiculous.