# How can users be older than site?

Tags: support, area-51

So recently "Startups" were finally launched. From Area 51 I can see that it is 9 days old.

[image]

However users up to index 78 are 10 days old.

> [image]

How could it be?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links.

Comment: @Rob You are welcome... any ideas?

Comment: Sarcasm... in case you were wondering.

Comment: @Rob You think I am stupid with my 100 years? ;-)

Comment: Oh, you were being sarcastic too, I see.

Comment: Pleasure to watch you two sarcasming each other, nicael and @Robert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cache, it's always cache. Really.

To know the site *real* age, just check the "member for" of the Community User:

> [image]

The stats on Area 51 proposals are heavily cached, and this includes the "days in beta" detail.

Comment: Tricky, never thought to use the community member. I always thought it was a global, special user that existed outside the realm of time.

Comment: Cheers @Qix actually I've already answered this once, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218006/152859).