# I thought the "old hat" was for well, old hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440645/betasystems-rodrigo-duarte) has earned the "old hat" on Stack Overflow. He has been a member for less than 2 years. I thought the [old hat was only for old timers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212246/how-do-i-earn-the-old-hat-hat), so how is this possible?

Here is a screen shot of his profile:

[image: old hat, new account]

Comment: He probably earned it on some other site.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: That's not true, because the popup says that he earned the hat on SO.

Comment: well, he only has 2 accounts SO and Programmers.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird then.

Comment: Definitely a bug, but I don't think it matters much.

Comment: That is also a good possibility. But that'd require maintaining a cookie for 3 and a half years. Not impossible either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logo is confusing. He didn't earn it on Stack Overflow. He earned it on **Stack Overflow in Portuguese**.

[image: Hover over icon]

Since the Portuguese Stack Overflow is still in private beta, it doesn't show up in his accounts list.

Comment: ah, the hover gets me once again! As usual, I'm on my tablet.

Comment: But I was sure private beta sites don't have hats... oh well guess I was wrong. :)

Comment: @Shadow Only new ones that didn't exist before December 16 when Winterbash started, but that was due to a [network configuration error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212207). I don't think they originally intended for Aviation and Stack Overflow Portuguese to participate in Winterbash.

Comment: I was able to sign up for the Portuguese SO just now! I thought Private Betas were... well... *Private*?

Comment: @Shiva Due to the nature of Stack Overflow in Portuguese, they don't have the Area 51 commitment requirement for that particular site.