# Don't show Private Beta sites in Leaderboard

Tags: feature-request, bug, winter-bash-2015

Just noticed this in the [Winter Bash Leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) when scrolling all the way down:

> [image]

Excited, I clicked to see the profiles on that site, e.g. [this one](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/users/369/programfox), just to be greeted with...

> [image]

In my opinion, Leaderboard should not show stats for sites still in private beta. Private beta sites are not displayed anywhere outside Area 51: not in [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current), and not in [stackexchange.com sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) - so I don't think Winter Bash should be the exception

Comment: Why not? What if I want to see how I rank on a private beta site?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 private beta sites are not displayed anywhere, not in your profile and not in the Sites list in stackexchange.com - so I don't think Winter Bash should be the exception. As for rank, well, with so few users I don't think it's really that relevant. :-)

Answer (score 8):

In years past hats have [not been turned on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212207/1438) for private betas since "the site should focus on being born, not wearing hats". This year, we only have one beta, but it's not really a traditional beta. So we didn't really think to exclude Documentation. (Since almost all the holdouts [opted in](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/winterbash-2015-participation) this year, the list was short: MathOverflow.) So in a sense, it's a bug and we screwed up.

On the other hand, Documentation isn't in a community-building phase, but a feature-building one. Every single person in the beta is, by the requirements of getting an invitation, part of Stack Overflow. It's a  lot less likely that hats will be a distraction than it would be if there were lots of users new to the network. So I personally don't care if the feature is turned on or not.

The folks developing and testing the new Documentation feature might not want it. It's pretty much up to them to decide (or not).

Comment: Where Documentation is a feature-building/official StackOverflow Corp site, I'd almost expect all SO behaviors to be in play, as they will be in the future.

Comment: So [tag:status-pending-users-decision]? :)

Comment: I'm glad, then, that Raspberry Pi recently got out of Beta :D. Will this change in later years if more betas **are** open at the time?

Comment: @HeatherBrown Raspberry Pi was a public beta, not private, so it would have gotten hats regardless.

Comment: Huh, TIL that there's even a docs beta - wish that the signup link had been sent to the people that sent in the Warlords of Documentation form...

Comment: @nneonneo That's peculiar, I got my invite via e-mail. Although it seems that the site was already a week old when I got it.Still, if you replied to the form you should have received an invitation... spam filtered, perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't seem like I received anything at all. (Come to think of it, I never got my swag either - wonder if the SO guys are just not getting anything to my address...)

Comment: @FatherChristmas, I signed up for the documentation beta through the blog post, but I never got an e-mail. Thats weird, I can't find the blog post.

Comment: @CalebKleveter: The invites for Documentation have been trickling out for weeks. We have tons of volunteers who are still waiting. Just hang tight: we'll get everyone in eventually. The feature will be in beta for another couple of months at least.

Comment: @nneonneo, same here. No swag. It's like it disappeared into thin air.